# How can I convert U2 Business Logic Subroutine’s multi-value data into .NET Objects such as DataSet/DataTable using U2 Toolkit for .NET?

Tags: subroutine, u2, universe, unidata, u2netdk

I have the following subroutine. It takes INPUT as argument 1 and sends multi-value data OUTPUT as argument 2.

SUBROUTINE MV_TO_DATASET_SELECT_SUBROUTINE(ARG_INPUT,ARG_OUTPUT)

x = ARG_INPUT
ARG_OUTPUT = "100":@VM:"101":@VM:"102":@VM:"103":@FM:"Nancy":@VM:"Andrew":@VM:"Janet":@VM:"Margaret":@FM:"01/06/1991":@VM:"06/07/1996":@VM:"11/08/1999":@VM:"12/10/2001"

RETURN

The Schema of above subroutine’s multi-value data  is as below.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("HireDate", typeof(DateTime));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achevieve this task one of the following ways:

- Use MV_To_DataTable() and DataTable_To_MV(). You can create schema of
  subroutine by dragging and dropping Empty DataTable into Empty
  DataSet Deginer.
- By draagging and dropping Visual Studio  Server Explorer’s U2
  Subroutine into DataSet Designer. U2 Subrotine returns
  resultset/dataset by executing API such as  ST=SQLExecDirect(@HSTMT,
  "SELECT F1 AS COL1,F2 AS COL2 ,F3 AS COL3 FROM @TMP SLIST 9 ORDER BY
  1")

### Use MV_To_DataTable() and DataTable_To_MV()

Create ASP.NET Web Application Project. Type ‘WebApplication_Subroutine’ in Project Name.
[image: create ap.net app]

Add Reference to U2NETDK Assembly (U2.Data.Client)
[image: Add Reference]

Change header ‘Welcome to ASP.NET!’ to ‘Welcome to U2 Toolkit for .NET Demo on Business Logic Subroutine’s multi-value string data to .NET DataSet!’
[image: change title]

Open ‘Default.aspx’ file and Go to Design Mode.
[image: open web page in design mode]

Do the following:

- Drag and Drop Button Control. Name it ‘Load’
- Drag and Drop Button Control. Name it ‘Update’
- Drag and Drop GridView Control.

  [image: drag and drop buttons]

Right Click on Solution Explorer. Select Add ->New Item-DataSet. In the Name box, type ‘Employee.xsd’

[image: new item - dataset]

Drag and Drop DataTable into Designer. Change the name to ‘Employee’ Table.
[image: drag DataTable]

Create 3 new Columns (U2 subroutine Schema):

- ID –  DataType : INT
- Name – DataType : STRING
- HireDate - DataType : DATE
  [image: create 3 cols]
  [image: datatype cols]

Open ‘Default.aspx’ file in Design Mode. Double Click ‘Load Button’. It will create Event handler Code behind.
[image: load evernt handler]

Cut and paste the following code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            U2ConnectionStringBuilder l = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder();
            l.Server = "127.0.0.1";
            l.UserID = "user";
            l.Password = "pass";
            l.Database = "HS.SALES";
            l.ServerType = "universe";
            string lconnstr = l.ToString();
            U2Connection c = new U2Connection();
            c.ConnectionString = lconnstr;
            c.Open();
            U2Command command = c.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "CALL MV_TO_DATASET_SELECT_SUBROUTINE(?,?)";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            U2Parameter p1 = new U2Parameter();
            p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            p1.Value = "";
            p1.ParameterName = "@arg_input";
            command.Parameters.Add(p1);
            U2Parameter p2 = new U2Parameter();
            p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            p2.Value = "";
            p2.ParameterName = "@arg_output";
            command.Parameters.Add(p2);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Employee.EmployeeDataTable dt = new Employee.EmployeeDataTable();

            command.Parameters[1].MV_To_DataTable(dt);

            Session["GridDataset"] = dt;


            this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

[image: load code]

Run the application. Press ‘Load’ Button.

[image: run asp.net app]

Open ‘Default.aspx’ file in Design Mode. Double click ‘Update Button’. It will create Event Handler in Code behind page.
Cut and Paste the following Code.

```
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["GridDataset"];

        //To TEST, change first row
        string s1 = (string)dt.Rows[0]["Name"];
        dt.Rows[0]["Name"] = s1 + "NewValue";


        // get the modified rows
        DataTable dt_changed = dt.GetChanges();

        //call DATASET_TO_MV_UPDATE_SUBROUTINE
        U2ConnectionStringBuilder l = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder();
        l.Server = "127.0.0.1";
        l.UserID = "user";
        l.Password = "pass";
        l.Database = "HS.SALES";
        l.ServerType = "universe";
        string lconnstr = l.ToString();
        U2Connection c = new U2Connection();
        c.ConnectionString = lconnstr;
        c.Open();
        U2Command command = c.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "CALL DATASET_TO_MV_UPDATE_SUBROUTINE(?)";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        U2Parameter p1 = new U2Parameter();
        p1.Value = "";
        p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        p1.ParameterName = "@arg_data";
        command.Parameters.Add(p1);

        command.Parameters[0].DataTable_To_MV(dt_changed);

        // modified data going to subroutine
        string lData = (string)command.Parameters[0].Value;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

[image: update code]

See the Modified Value in the Debugger when you click Update Button.
[image: debugger]

### U2 Subrotine returns resultset/dataset

Create U2 Data Connection in Visual Studio Server Explorer. Expand Store Procedures Node.
[image: server explorer u2 connection]

Go to subroutine that returns resultset/dataset. Drag and Drop subroutine into DataSet Designer.
It shows INPUT argument and resultset/dataset columns.

[image: drag and drop subroutine]

Comment: For this answer we have used the following subroutines: 

SUBROUTINE MV_TO_DATASET_SELECT_SUBROUTINE(ARG_INPUT,ARG_OUTPUT) x = ARG_INPUT ARG_OUTPUT = "100":@VM:"101":@VM:"102":@VM:"103":@FM:"Nancy":@VM:"Andrew":@VM:"Janet":@VM:"Margaret":@FM:"01/06/1991":@VM:"06/07/1996":@VM:"11/08/1999":@VM:"12/10/2001" RETURN AND for update ( not completed ) subroutine SUBROUTINE DATASET_TO_MV_UPDATE_SUBROUTINE(modified_data) *do update RETURN

Comment: Could anyone enlighten me on how we convert the record to the output format shown in @RajanKumar example? My data is coming back in a different format. I am however using READNEXTTUPLE. My current format is looking like this: 

`123þABCþDEFÿ
456þDEFþGHIÿ`